# Buildroot : Which gcc for cross compilation?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, arm, buildroot

I am newbee to buildroot. I can see multiple gccs in buildroot. I assume all are for cross compilation. What are the difference between those ?

```
buildroot-2012.05/output/host/usr/bin/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc
buildroot-2012.05/output/host/usr/libexec/gcc
buildroot-2012.05/output/host/usr/arm-linux/bin/gcc
buildroot-2012.05/output/host/usr/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/gcc
```

Comment: Is there any soft link between them?

Comment: @JermaineXu thanks arm-linux is a link to arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one you should use is `buildroot-2012.05/output/host/usr/bin/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc`. The other ones are purely internals binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Use arm-linux-gcc or arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc.
In fact arm-linux-gcc is soft linked to arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc.